# Icons in Print CSS don't retain colour

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I have a bootstrap based file which has some print specific CSS, but none that affect glyph icons. I have some icons which need to remain coloured when printed, but they appear in black and white.

I've tried using the following to prevent this, but it doesn't work:

```
@media print and (color) {
   * {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap media print there is the following rule:

```
@media print
*, :after, :before {....
    color: #000!important;
   ....
}
```

This is the rule you have to overwrite to make glyph coloured

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
            @media print
        {
            .title_head
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: gray !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
            }
        }
```

It works for me